# ViewModel method doesn't return object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have implemented MVVM in WP8, but I have problems with calling method from my ViewModel Class, here is part of my App.xaml.cs class from where I call method from my ViewModel Class:

```
 private static PrasanjaViewModel viewModel=null;

    /// <summary>
    /// A static ViewModel used by the views to bind against.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The MainViewModel object.</returns>
    public static PrasanjaViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
            if (viewModel == null)
            {
                viewModel = new PrasanjaViewModel();
                viewModel.LoadData();
            }

            return viewModel;
        }
    }
```

And here is the implemented LoadData() method from my PrasanjaViewModel class:

```
 public void LoadData()
    {
        PrasanjaViewModel prasanje1 = GetPrasanje(); 

        IsDataLoaded = true;
    }

    public PrasanjaViewModel GetPrasanje()
    {
        var prasanje = new PrasanjaViewModel();
        SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH);
        var query = db.Table<Prasanja>().Where(x => x.id == 3);
        var result = query.ToList();
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            prasanje.id = item.id;
            prasanje.Tekst = item.Tekst;
        }
        return prasanje;
    }
```

So the method GetPrasanje() returns properly the object **prasanje**. And **prasanje1** is returned properly. But when **return viewModel
** is executed it returns NULL. I can't find where is the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix: Change the return type of the `LoadData()` method from `void` to `PrasanjaViewModel`, and add `return prasanja1;` to the end of that method. The problem with this is you're creating an instance of PasanjaViewModel, which is used to create *another* instance of PrasanjaViewModel, and the second instance (where the data is loaded into) is discarded and never used. You'll also have to change the line in your getter to `viewModel = viewModel.LoadData();`, but then you're keeping the second instance and discarding the first!

I'm making a guess at what you are attempting, but try this:

1. Make your `GetPrasanje()` method static.
2. Instead of calling `new PrasanjaViewModel()` in your getter, call the static method.
3. Remove the `LoadData()` method, since the `GetPrasanje()` does the loading.

The static method is a "factory" method that will create a new viewmodel object for you with the data.

Also, at the end of your `GetPrasanje()` method, you're iterating over your database query results, and assigning the values of various rows to prasanje.Id and prasanje.Tekst over and over again, each time overwriting the value you just assigned. This is probably also not what you want. Instead, PrasanjaViewModel should have a property that is some type of collection (like a `List<ResultItem> ResultItems`, where `ResultItem` is another class that holds one of the rows from the database).

On the other hand, it looks like you're attempting to query and obtain a *single* row from your database. In this case, add `.Single()` to your query, and get rid of the foreach loop.

Here is slightly modified code:

```
private static PrasanjaViewModel viewModel=null;

/// <summary>
/// A static ViewModel used by the views to bind against.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The MainViewModel object.</returns>
public static PrasanjaViewModel ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
        if (viewModel == null)
        {
            viewModel = PresanjaViewModel.GetPresanje();
        }

        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public static PrasanjaViewModel GetPrasanje()
{
    var prasanje = new PrasanjaViewModel();

    SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH);
    var result = db.Table<Prasanja>().Where(x => x.id == 3).Single();
    prasanje.id = result.id;
    prasanje.Tekst = result.Tekst;

    return prasanje;
}
```

I'm also curious what Prasanja means... :)